# Motherboard (Gigabyte B450) cannot retain BIOS settings

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, bios

I am using Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro Wifi motherbard, AMD Ryzen 7 2600x, Corsair DDR4 2x8GB 3200Mhz RAM (CMK16GX4M2B3200C16). My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

I have this weird problem with my desktop PC. Sometimes, PC fails to boot up because I cannot see the bios boot-up screen. To fix this problem, I have to pull out the power plug, wait for a pop sound, then put back the power plug. Now, I can see the bios boot-up screen on boot-up. The problem is this action of pulling out and plugging back the power plug **sometimes** causes the BIOS settings to be reset to default. This happens **sometimes** only when I was using bios firmware version F2. Yesterday, I upgraded bios firmware to F5. Now, the action of pulling out and plugging back the power plug **ALWAYS** causes the BIOS settings to be reset to default.

This is a problem because I need to change BIOS settings to use 3200Mhz RAM clock and run Ubuntu virtual machines on Virtualbox.

I bought the motherboard a few weeks ago. It is unlikely the battery can run out so soon.

Comment: Sounds like the board is bad. Maybe you should RMA it.

Comment: I'm ignorant. All the components are mounted on the motherboard. What is an easy way to RMA the motherboard? Plug out all components and send board to manufacturer?

Comment: Yes. If the board is new then open a case with the vendor or with the manufacturer to have it replaced.

Comment: @Appleoddity, thanks. I guess one has to bite the bullet. The problem is ... for some people, downtime is more costly than the motherboard itself. Never expect this will happen. Gigabyte is a brand name for motherboards.

Comment: I understand. Contact the manufacturer, they may have tech support who can solve the issue. But if the board is bad, and it sounds like it is, you’ll have to replace it. If downtime is a problem, see if you can do what is an “advanced” replacement. You’ll pay for a second board and the manufacturer will ship it to you, then you’ll ship the defective back and get a refund.

Comment: Not all customer have the expertise to plug out components and plug it back onto another board. Those who are not skilful will end up damaging other components. No more Gigabyte for me in future.
Thanks for your advice. It's bitter medicine but I can't think of better solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

After I uninstall Avast anti-virus software, my problem with BIOS not being able to retain settings was solved. This solution is specific to my PC. May not work for others.